# Hive External table retrieve query (New to Hive )

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created below mention external table..

```
create external table if not exists sensor.building1 (BuildingID int,BuildingMgr string , BuildingAge string, HVACproduct string , Country string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Loaded the table by using below query..

```
load data  inpath '/user/cloudera/sensor/SensorFiles/building.csv' into table sensor.building1;
```

When I am trying to retrieve the `buildingID` column using below query, but I am getting null value..

```
select a.BuildingID 
from sensor.building1 as a 
limit 10;
```

Please guide me where I am doing something  wrong

Comment: Can you provide few lines of your input file ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a CSV file into hive table but hive's default field delimiter is '\001'
So while you tring to load data from csv (I am assuming its ',' separated) its get failed.

You can create table like :

```
create external table test1(country string, name string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: You can go through the [hive language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormat,StorageFormat,andSerDe) for more details.